# Динамическая замена src в iframe?

Tags: html, javascript

Всем привет! У меня есть два дива!

```
<div id="button"><div>
<div id="main"><iframe src="" width="" height="" ></iframe></div>
```

Как сделать так чтобы при клике на `button`, изменялся `src` в `iframe` второго дива?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ReinRaus/vTX9A/
**jQuery**

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    $('#main iframe')[0].src= '/';
});
```

**pureJS**

```
var button2= document.getElementById('button2');
button2.onclick= function() {
    document.getElementById('main').getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src="/";
};
```

Comment: Вы супер!!!